# Twincat 3 how to declare struct within struct

Tags: struct, declaration, twincat

Currently we have several STRUCTS declared which I would like to combine into 1 STRUCT. Is this possible and how do I do this? I would like to have this feature because it would cleanup our project.

**Current:**

```
TYPE ST_MAIN_HMI : 
STRUCT
  Var 1 : BOOL;
  Var 2 : BOOL;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE

TYPE ST_MAIN_CFG : 
STRUCT
  Var 1 : BOOL;
  Var 2 : BOOL;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE

TYPE ST_MAIN : 
STRUCT
  HMI : ST_MAIN_HMI;
  CFG : ST_MAIN_CFG;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE

Main.HMI.Var1 := TRUE;
Main.CFG.Var2 := FALSE;
```

**Desired:**

```
TYPE ST_MAIN : 
STRUCT
  TYPE HMI : 
  STRUCT
    Var 1 : BOOL;
    Var 2 : BOOL;
  END_STRUCT
  END_TYPE
  TYPE CFG :
  STRUCT
    Var 1 : BOOL;
    Var 2 : BOOL;
  END_STRUCT
  END_TYPE
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE

Main.HMI.Var1 := TRUE;
Main.CFG.Var2 := FALSE;
```

Answer (score 1):

That is impossible because it would be against the IEC 61131-3.

You have to stay in seperated DUTS in your project. Maybe folders will help you to sort your project.